# Trying to enqueue script - Nothing Happens

Tags: php, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to enqueuer a script after registering it but I am getting an error.

This is the script:

```
function _test() {
    console.log("Test");
}
```

That's the PHP:

```
function fsg_shortURL() {
    echo "Funtion Called";
    wp_register_script('_test','/wp-content/themes/theme-child/js/test.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('_test');
}

add_shortcode( 'fsg', 'fsg_shortURL' );
```

The console's suppouse to log `Test` but nothing happens..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you've to call the function to execute it:

```
function _test() {
  console.log("Test");
}
_test();
```

Comment: It works. Thanks but why is that? I thought `wp_enqueue_script('_test');` is suppose to call the function is it not?

Comment: no, you're including a .js script called `test.js` assigning it an id `_test` ( you can see inspecting the source in the head section) but the function `_test()` of the .js file itself must be executed by javascript.. probably the over-usage of "test" may have confused you, so maybe change the js function to `console_test()` and execute it leaving the rest unchanged to better understand

Answer (score 0):

To add a file located in a directory of the active theme, you have to use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

```
wp_register_script(
      "idScript"
    , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/script.js"
);
```

In you question, you speak about a shortcode.
It's better to store shortcode in a plugin. then, you can get the file URL with https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

```
wp_enqueue_script(
     "pluginScript"
    , plugins_url("js/script.js", __FILE__)
);
```